# Question moved from a site where it should have remained

Tags: discussion, scope, migration, migrated-questions

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40945026/3545273) that had been migrated from [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

I could understand and answer it. Then I realized that my answer was not involving any coding part, and that both the question and my (now accepted) answer should be on-topic on CS, while they are rather border line on SO.

What would be the *correct* handling for such a case:

- should I have edited the question to remove any strictly Python language part and flag it to be migrated back before answering?
- should I now flag it for migration?
- should I just not care and move on?

Comment: The tricky part is that you don't know where it belongs unless you have the answer. Computer scientists might blame the language and hence look to SO for a solution, programmers might blame the algorithm and hence look to CS for a solution… It appears to me it can live in either place.

Comment: @deceze: I do not agree. Even without an in depth knowledge of Python, one can see that the two method do not use the same algorithm for computing an approximation of the derivative - but OP could/should have make it more clear. And comparingl different numerica algorithms seems on topic on CS.